# Approach and Methods for migrating AngularJS 1.4 app to Angular 8

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade a large Enterprise application from AngularJS v1.4 to Angular 8 and trying to look for various approaches for the same.

1. Since we are on angularJS1.4, we cannnot use ngUpgrade Module provided by Angular team because in order to do so we need to first migrate AngularJS to version 1.6+ and controllers to components. (Hence, this approach is discarded).
2. A complete rewrite of the application in Angular 8.
3. I read about single spa where two frameworks can coexist together.
4. Using an iframe to load angularjs in angular app and then gradually re-write the new code in angular.
5. Create a completely different application in Angular, then from my AngularJS navigate to new Angular application as per route. Both the apps will run on different ports locally, but will run on same domain on server hence sharing the cookies and localstorage.

We are thinking of going with approach 5.

Which of the following approach should I go with or is there any other approach I can go?

Any other inputs will be appreciated.

Comment: please check given link - https://angular.io/guide/upgrade

Comment: (option 2) You do not need to change all your controllers to components to upgrade to angular 1.6+ and you do not need to do that either to make use of the ngUpgrade module *unless* you want to host parts of your angularjs inside angular8 components. You could create angular8 components and services and host them inside your angularjs code and then actively migrate/convert your angularjs code to angular8 code until you get to the point where everything has been migrated.

Comment: @Igor We will anyway not be using any angularjs controllers as we are targeting for complete rewrite. However, is there any way we can coexist new angular8  and angularjs in single application as we are also currently using gulp for various tasks like proxying API and other stuff while angular uses angular-cli/webpack.

Also, since active development is ongoing, we might not get complete bandwidth for rewriting in Angular8. Hence, coexisting both apps seems the only solution

Comment: Read the link @piyushjain posted, specifically [Using Angular Components from AngularJS Code](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#using-angular-components-from-angularjs-code). I recommend you take your existing code base and create a PoC where you have a dummy anuglar8 component and try to load it in your existing app. This should be possible without significant changes (you will need to upgrade your angularjs version) and you should *not* have to change angularjs controllers to components.

Comment: You can then migrate your app one part at a time (part is subjective, could be module/file/whatever) from anuglarjs to angular8.